# I'm trying to display data that i fetched from my local server but I receive an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

***HERE IS THE COMPONENT:***
this component is supposed to display data that is fetched from my localhost server

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


function FindJob(){
    const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/getjob")
        .then(res => {
            const results = res.json();
            setJobs(results);

        },
        (error) => setError(error)
        )
    }, []);

    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(jobs);
        return <div>
            {jobs.map(job => (
                    <h2>{job.post}</h2>
                ))}
            </div>
    }
}
export default FindJob;
```

***THIS IS THE ERROR I GET ON RUNNING THE REACT APP***
yet i have written it just like the example in react.org about ajax calls

×

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): jobs.map is not a function
FindJob
C:/Users/user/Desktop/ben/jobconnect/jc-front/src/components/findjob.jsx:23
  20 |     console.log(error);
  21 | } else {
  22 |     console.log(jobs);
> 23 |     return <div>
     | ^  24 |         {jobs.map(job => (
  25 |                 <h2>{job.post}</h2>
  26 |             ))}
View compiled
▶ 17 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/user/Desktop/ben/jobconnect/jc-front/src/components/findjob.jsx:12
   9 | fetch("http://localhost:5000/getjob")
  10 | .then(res => {
  11 |     const results = res.json();
> 12 |     setJobs(results);
     | ^  13 |     
  14 | },
  15 | (error) => setError(error)
View compiled
```

this data hasn't been displayed but i am able to console.log it

***THIS IS THE FETCHED DATA FROM MY LOCAL SERVER:***

```
[
{
"_id": "5ed8f1494a9a902b38986dba",
"post": "general manager",
"organization": "oracle",
"description": "someone to oversee day to day operaetions",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5edf615e274cdb3c94847e5a",
"post": "developer",
"organization": "andela",
"description": "full stack developer",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5ee3a541e29e9e0be44cd370",
"__v": 0
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `res.json()` is async so you need to chain them with further `.then()` calls - or use `async` / `await` to avoid lots of `.then()` calls or creating a callback hell.

So instead try as the following - just followed your code snippet:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/getjob")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
         setJobs(data);
      });
}, []);
```

I removed the error handling just to see how to use `fetch` with `.json()` so don't forget to put it back in your code. Suggested read is [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) where you can find an example for the above mentioned solution.

I hope this helps!

Comment: @bensonmiano Awesome, happy to help here! If the solution worked, please consider upvoting or accepting as the answer for your question, thanks!